# Python: Parsing erf file works under linux but doesn't work under windows

Tags: python-2.7, wireshark

I have implemented a script to parse ERF file to get the DNS records from the packets. The script works under Linux but DOES NOT work under Windows.

I have tried to simplify it and read only two packets from the file and the result was totally wrong.

Here is the output for the first two packets:

```
rlen 1232
wlen 1213
ts:  (5822080496043415499L,)
rec len:  1232
protocol:  6  rem  1180
tcp
src port:  59626
remaining length based on the erf header 1160 remaining length based in IP total length 1155
----------------------
rlen 44076
wlen 13638
ts:  (246640611164160L,)
rec len:  44076
protocol:  9  rem  44024
----------------------
```

for the first packet the output is correct, but for the second one everything is wrong. What I did was reading the record length from the ERF header to keep track of the packet boundaries. When I printed the payload of the tcp I found that the erf header of the next packet was in the payload of tcp. This problem didn't occur when I ran the code under linux.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    argv= sys.argv
    outputFile=''
    inputFile=''
    dnsPacketCounter=0
    ethH = {}
    ipHeader = {}
    ipH = {}
    totalPackets=0



    if len(argv) ==1:
        print 'erfParser.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(0)
    elif len(argv) == 2:
        if argv[1] == '-h':
            print 'erfParser.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(0)
    elif len(argv) == 5:
        if argv[1] == '-i':
            inputFile = argv[2].strip()
        elif argv[3] == '-i':
            inputFile = argv[4].strip()
        if argv[1] == '-o':
            outputFile = argv[2].strip()
        elif argv[3] == '-o':
            outputFile= argv[4].strip()
    else: 
        # Open the trace file
        print 'erfParser.py -i <inputfile> -o <outputfile>'
        sys.exit(0)
    try:
        packets = open(inputFile , 'r+')
    except IOError:
        print 'The file: ',inputFile,' not found.'
        sys.exit(0)
    try:
        outFile=open(outputFile+'.txt', 'w+')
    except IOError:
        print 'The file: ',outputFile,' can not be opened.'
        sys.exit(0)

    ts=packets.read(8)
    i=0
    while ts:
        erf={}
        hdr = packets.read(8)
        #print ts.encode('hex')
        totalPackets=totalPackets+1
        erf= getERFHeader(ts,hdr)
        print 'rlen',erf['rlen']
        print 'wlen',erf['wlen']
        print 'ts: ',erf['ts']
        remainingLength=erf['rlen']- 16
        print 'rec len: ',erf['rlen']
        if erf['type'] == 0x07:
            ext=packets.read(8)
            remainingLength=remainingLength- 8
        pad=packets.read(2) # pad
        remainingLength=remainingLength- 2
        ethH= packets.read(14) # ethernet header `16 bytes
        remainingLength=remainingLength- 14    
        ipHeader= packets.read(20) #ip header length is 20 bytes
        remainingLength=remainingLength- 20
        ipH= getIPHeader(ipHeader)

        print 'protocol: ',ipH['protocol'],' rem ',remainingLength
        if ipH['protocol'] ==TCP:
            print 'tcp'
            hdr = packets.read(20)
            remainingLength=remainingLength- 20
            tcpHeader=getTCPHeader(hdr)
            tcpPayload= packets.read(remainingLength)
            print 'src port: ',tcpHeader['srcPort']
           # print 'tcp payload in hex: ',tcpPayload.encode('hex')
            print 'remaining length based on the erf header',remainingLength,'remaining length based in IP total length' ,ipH['totalL']-40
        print '----------------------'
        ts=packets.read(8)

        i=i+1
        if i==2:
            break;

    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Yes, I can tell you that you're opening the file in text mode rather than binary mode:

> ```
> packets = open(inputFile , 'r+')
> ```

To quote [the Python documentation for `open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open):

> Modes `'r+'`, `'w+'` and `'a+'` open the file for updating (reading and writing); note that `'w+'` truncates the file. Append `'b'` to the mode to open the file in binary mode, on systems that differentiate between binary and text files; on systems that don’t have this distinction, adding the `'b'` has no effect.

UN*Xes such as Linux are "systems that don't have this distinction", because the Python `open()` is modeled after the UN*X version of the "standard I/O library", in which lines end with a `\n`.  On Windows, lines end with `\r\n`, and opens in the "standard I/O library" can either:

- open in text mode, in which the `\r\n` at the ends of lines, when read, are shown to the program as a `\n`, and a `\n`, when written to a line, is written as `\r\n`, so that programs written for UN*X can work on Windows without having to worry about the end-of-line sequence;
- open in binary mode, in which case a read gives you exactly the bytes that are in the file, and a write puts the bytes given to it into the file;

so it's a system that "[differentiates] between binary and text files", at least in some of the I/O libraries.  (At the lowest level of I/O, namely the `CreateFile()`, `ReadFile()`, and `WriteFile()` calls, Windows makes no such distinction - it treats files as sequences of raw bytes, with no "open as text" option, just as UN*X systems do with `open()`, `read()`, and `write()` - but at all levels of I/O intended to be somewhat UN*X-compatible, they provide a text vs. binary option.)

ERF files are binary files, so you need to open with `'rb+'` or `'r+b'`, not `'r+'`.  That will make no difference on UN*Xes such as Linux, but will give you raw binary data on Windows.

(Actually, just `'rb'` will suffice - if you don't plan to write to the file you're reading, the `+` isn't necessary, and creates the risk of accidentally overwriting the file.)